# In the Jupyter Notebook, using geopandas, the x- y-axis is not showing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

```
import geopandas
    
map_df = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
map_df.plot()
```

Error Traceback and Output:

[image]

Comment: Which version of geopandas do you have? Check using ```print(geopandas.__version__) ``` Works fine with ```0.9.0```.

Comment: Thank you Serge, I had only just installed it, turns out to be 0.6.2. I will update it: conda install -c conda-forge geopanda=0.10

Answer (score 1):

The map has a transparent background where the axes are. Since the axes are black by default and your background is also black, you can't see them. But they are there :).

You can specify the background using matplotlib.

```py
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map_df = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = map_df.plot(ax=ax)
fig.patch.set_facecolor('pink')
```

[image: result]

Comment: You my good friend are the best!